# keycloak-spring-boot-starter for Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

In my Spring Boot application, I'm integrating Keycloak to externalize the security. The version of the Spring Boot I use in my project is 2.2.4.RELEASE, however I checked the latest Keycloak 8 pom.xml and in it's dependencies, there is a hardcoded version of Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE in file `org/keycloak/keycloak-spring-boot-starter/8.0.2/keycloak-spring-boot-starter-8.0.2.pom`

```
    <properties>
      <spring-boot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>
```

How to solve this problem without Spring Boot version downgrade? I can't change the keycloak version, other in our solution systems use it. I also don't want Spring Boot to drive all the other versions, not the Keycloak, which is just one of many other components.

Comment: Do not esitate to comment why my answer doesn't solve your problem (or accept it...)

Comment: Hi ch4mp, I didn't try to solve it as it didn't cause any harm. What I did however was, that I have written a Maven plugin, that walked through whole dependency tree and collected all libraries and their versions and written it on output. I found, that Java import mechanism is utterly broken by design, as I found there are sometimes even 20 (!!!!) versions of some libraries in one Spring Boot project, Maven picks one and it somehow magically works. It's a mystery to me how the programmers were able to make their libraries compatible. After I saw that, this problem was no longer important to me

Comment: Eclipse has a really good plugin for Maven. How maven chooses dependencies is nothing but magic. You might refer to many other responses about that, like this one for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/50272111/619830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak produces OpenID complient JWT. Configuring spring-security to parse this JWT into something else than `KeycloackAuthenticationToken` is not so hard.

As so, you don't have to use their lib. You may use instead `JwtAuthenticationToken` or any other `Authentication` of your choice, even create one of your own.

In [a repo of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons), you'll find a [short tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) and a few [working samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) for both servlet and reactive apps.

Note in above samples, `OAuthenticationToken<OpenidClaimSet>` is an `Authentication` implementation I created to work with OpenID authorizations servers (not only Keycloak). Source are in the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

Current I am using below dependency, I followed this [youtube](https://youtu.be/TrASdBQu2_k) tutorial for integrating keykloak to spring boot,
& It works fine.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: It's exactly what `webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken` sample in the repo I linked does. If you compare it to `webmvc-oauthentication`, you'll see that later is simpler (configure from application.properties:  authorities mapping, CORS, CSRF, stateless session-management, optionally mutli-issuers, and more) and also provides with tooling for security rules unit-testing.